# Simple Jquery text animation fine in jsfiddle but not on site

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I'm using jquery to quickly deliver some simple brand messages by way of introduction when a visitor first comes to the site.

This works fine in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bellamystudio/76ZjF/) but on [the site](http://dev.1ofk.com) the messages are flashing up multiple times and the whole thing is generally broken.

Some times it plays fine once, but if you refresh the page it breaks - this behaviour doesn't happen in jsFiddle, so another script must be interfering with it, but I can't see what in Firebug.

Has anyone else encountered similar weirdness with queuing up animations?

Incidentally I've tried `queue()` and `dequeue()` for this but they were no help...

Comment: add the code from your site to your question and people will probably be able to help you. If it works on a fiddle and not your site then obviously the error lies with your site, maybe some other jquery code is broken etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take out the `getScript()` in your index page and include the slideshow code directly in the page.  Clearly, `getScript()` isn't working as there's no alert being triggered by it as you've specified in your code.  What's puzzling, though, is that no errors are being thrown.

I'd also question why you're doing what's essentially an ajax load of a javascript file into what is likely a one-time use type script (not used globally throughout the page I'm guessing)  What you're doing is adding an additional, unnecessary http hit to your page, which negatively affects your site's performance more than just having the code right in the page.  Will this one file affect the page dramatically?  No....but if you do it hundreds of times and you're a high traffic site, you could have an issue.

Comment: Originally the script was part of my plugins.js file. I've since bundled it out as a standalone file and on the homepage I include that file last. I'm really not sure what was causing the animation to replay the same section so many times but moving it to its own file seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks bpeterson for your input!!